# Uso de "por favor" e "favor"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

No exemplo abaixo, é correto o uso de **favor**, sem o **por** na frente?

> **Favor** solicitar a alteração.

Ao invés disso,

> **Por favor** solicitar a alteração.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**"favor"** (**faça o favor de**) é seguido por verbo no infinitivo e soa mais como um aviso mas pode até mesmo parecer uma ordem, dependendo de contexto e intonação.

- Favor solicitar a alteração.
- Favor não sujar o tapete.
- Favor não cuspir no chão.
- Favor apresentar seus documentos no balcão.

**Por favor**, soa mais como um pedido pessoal e também soa mais educado. Não é seguido por verbo no infinitivo, mas sim por imperativo (afirmativo ou negativo)

- Por favor, solicite a alteração
- Por favor, não suje o tapete.
- Por favor, avise a Maria que estou aqui.
- Por favor, apresente seus documentos no balcão.

Answer (score 7):

De acordo com o [Prof. Dílson Catarino na *Gramática Online*:](http://www.gramaticaonline.com.br/page.aspx?id=9&iddetalhe=610&idsubcat=82&idcateg=7)

**Por favor** é uma expressão de cortesia usada quando se quer pedir algo a alguém.

Neste caso o correto é `por favor`, deve-se utilizar a preposição por.

O verbo que vier imediatamente à sua frente deverá estar no modo imperativo, usado para ordem, pedido, conselho ou apelo.

O infinitivo pode ser usado no lugar do imperativo.

Answer (score 5):

Para mim ambas parecem corretas. A segunda versão soa mais natural se o *por favor* vier no final:

> Solicitar a alteração, por favor.

Eu também tenho a impressão (embora não tenha nada à mão para sustentar essa hipótese) de que o uso de *favor* (sem o *por*) envolve algum tipo de elipse:

> **[?]** favor solicitar a alteração

O que estaria pressuposto seria o próprio *por*, ou talvez um *é*.

Comment: *É favor solicitar*... respeita a gramática convencional, e é comum em Portugal; *por favor, solicitar*... parecem-me fragmentos.

Comment: Por outro lado, encontrei exemplos de *por favor, + infinitivo*, e a resposta do Denis diz que isso é possível. Já não digo nada! Parece os comandos nas forças armadas, *apresentar arma, direita, volver!*, sem o *por favor*.